# AJAX does not send POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

First of all, I have already read through many other posts and tried different things, but no solution approach has worked so far.

My problem: ajax does not send the POST data.

fillTable.js

```
function fillTableWithData(htmlID, tableSQL, colsSQL, orderSQL){
  var jsondata = new FormData();
  jsondata.append("action", htmlID);
  jsondata.append("table", tableSQL);
  jsondata.append("cols", colsSQL);
  jsondata.append("order", orderSQL);
  $.ajax({
      url:"table.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,
      data: jsondata,
      success:function(result){
        //   $(htmlID).html(result);
        alert("test");
      }
  });
}
```

table.php

```
<?php
  require('db.php');
  echo (count($_POST)); // result is 0
  if(isset($_POST['action'])){ // not set
    if($_POST['action'] == "getDataAsRows"){
      getDataAsRows($_POST['table'], $_POST['cols'], $_POST['order']);
    }
  }  

  function getDataAsRows($table, $cols, $order) {
     ...
  }
?>
```

Both files are inside the same folder:

/scripts/fillTable.js

/scripts/table.php

The url should not be a problem, since the php code prints out the length of $_POST.

Comment: The folder on the server doesn't matter. URLs in js files are relative to the current HTML file.

Comment: Good to know, but anyways, since the php is executed, it should not be a problem with the URL, right? I also tried different urls

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `method` option was added in 1.9, it was called `type` before that.

Comment: @Barmar I tried the type and method option. Both did not work

Comment: @GrafiCode That shouldn't make a difference. That controls how `$.ajax` processes the response.

Comment: have you tried removing the `contentType:false` and `processData:false` and then simply passing you data as an object to the data variable like this:
`data: { "action": htmlID, "table": tableSQL, "cols": colsSQL, "order": orderSQL }`
Because as far as i remember JQuery's ajax function does alot to try and format you input for you. 

Comment: @Sicet7 Is right. You only need to use `FormData` if you're trying to upload a file.

Comment: @Sicet7 already tried it without FormData. Result was the same

Comment: @Kingvinst also with the `processData` field removed?
Because that should only be false in cases where you are expecting something other that scalar values in your data.
Also setting `contentType` to `false` makes JQuery not send the Content-Type header making PHP not able to parse the data into the `$_POST` superglobal.
So if you want to see exactly what the raw POST data is then you can add `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` to you file to see the raw POST data is.